# What would cause filter differences between machines

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am using `scipy` (v. 0.14.0) to filter some data with the following code:

```
    [Bh, Ah] = scipy.signal.butter(5, 0.2 / 250.0, 'highpass')
    filt_data = scipy.signal.filtfilt(Bh, Ah, data, padtype=None)
```

Running this on two separate machines:

1. Linux-3.13.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
2. Linux-3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.0.1406-Core

give slightly different results for the filtered outputs even though the filter coefficients `Bh` and `Ah` are identical (to the 30th decimal place).

Does anyone have any ideas as to what would be the root cause of this or where to look for a root cause?    I'm using Python 2.7.6 and numpy 1.8.1

Comment: A possibility could be that the utilized BLAS and LAPACK libraries a different (ATLAS or Intel MKL, ...).

Comment: Numerical rounding error typically varies between machines, because of different CPU (parallelization), different library versions etc. This is a general issue in numerical computing, http://raim2013.lip6.fr/theme/PDF/Reproductibilite/%5BRevol%5D%20Numerical%20reproducibility%20in%20HPC%20-%20issues%20in%20floating-point%20arithmetic%20and%20in%20interval%20arithmetic.pdf

Comment: @Dietrich I'm pretty sure that BLAS and LAPACK are unrelated. `signal.filtfilt` ultimately calls `signal.sigtools._linear_filter`, which is [implemented in 'pure' C++](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/lfilter.c.src) and makes no calls to BLAS or LAPACK functions. I suppose that the differences could conceivably be compiler-related.

Comment: How big are the numerical differences you're seeing? Could you give us a complete example that reproduces the issue?